# async_connect hanging on socket_ops::accept in socket_select_interrupter::open_descriptors

Tags: boost-asio

Clent side of client-server application running multiple sockets hangs under the load. Analysis shows one of communication threads hanging on async_connect with the following stack trace:

```
ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForSingleObject()  + 0xa bytes  
mswsock.dll!SockWaitForSingleObject()  + 0x13c bytes    
mswsock.dll!WSPAccept()  + 0x2a3a bytes 
ws2_32.dll!WSAAccept()  + 0xaf bytes    
ws2_32.dll!accept()  + 0x12 bytes   
boost::asio::detail::socket_select_interrupter::open_descriptors()  Line 88 + 0x31 bytes    C++
boost::asio::detail::select_reactor::select_reactor(boost::asio::io_service & io_service={...})  Line 47 + 0x90 bytes   C++
boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::detail::select_reactor>(boost::asio::io_service & owner={...})  Line 81 + 0x1f bytes C++
boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(const boost::asio::io_service::service::key & key={...}, boost::asio::io_service::service * (boost::asio::io_service &)* factory=0x0000000036cbdda8)  Line 123 + 0x6 bytes    C++
boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::start_connect_op(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type & impl={...}, boost::asio::detail::reactor_op * op=0x000000002b9cea30, const sockaddr * addr=0x000000002870f5f0, unsigned __int64 addrlen=16)  Line 550 + 0x45 bytes    C++
boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::async_connect<boost::asio::detail::wrapped_handler<boost::asio::io_service::strand,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,Replication::PTCPChannel,boost::system::error_code const & __ptr64>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Replication::PTCPChannel> >,boost::arg<1> > > > >(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::implementation_type & impl={...}, const boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> & peer_endpoint={...}, boost::asio::detail::wrapped_handler<boost::asio::io_service::strand,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,Replication::PTCPChannel,boost::system::error_code const &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Replication::PTCPChannel> >,boost::arg<1> > > > * handler=0x000000002b9cea30)  Line 497  C++
boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::async_connect<boost::asio::detail::wrapped_handler<boost::asio::io_service::strand,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,Replication::PTCPChannel,boost::system::error_code const & __ptr64>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Replication::PTCPChannel> >,boost::arg<1> > > > >(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::implementation_type & impl={...}, const boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> & peer_endpoint={...}, const boost::asio::detail::wrapped_handler<boost::asio::io_service::strand,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,Replication::PTCPChannel,boost::system::error_code const &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Replication::PTCPChannel> >,boost::arg<1> > > > & handler={...})  Line 209   C++
boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::async_connect<boost::asio::detail::wrapped_handler<boost::asio::io_service::strand,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,Replication::PTCPChannel,boost::system::error_code const & __ptr64>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Replication::PTCPChannel> >,boost::arg<1> > > > >(const boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> & peer_endpoint={...}, const boost::asio::detail::wrapped_handler<boost::asio::io_service::strand,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,Replication::PTCPChannel,boost::system::error_code const &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<Replication::PTCPChannel> >,boost::arg<1> > > > & handler={...})  Line 723    C++
```

Can anyone suggest why is internal socket connection hanging? The hanging happens after a few hours of the load test and is eventually blocking the whole application. 
Since this is an internal socket (listening on loopback IP), can anyone explain who is supposed to connect to it and when? Is there a some kind of internal limit of how many connection to loopback ports is possible by asio socket services?

Is there a preferred way to shut down hanging thread in this case?

The app in question is windows app currently running onWin2k8R2 or Win 2k12 R2, boost version used is 1.54.

Answer (score 0):

Could a firewall potentially be blocking connection to the target port? That is one possibility mentioned [in this bug report](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5114)

Answer (score 0):

Look for maxconnection (outbound limit = 2 on outbound for asp.net)